# Linux DNS Multi tenant

Tags: linux, networking, dns

I need to setup a multi-tenant DNS solution in Linux DNS Server. Currently I serve multiple companies:
Company ABC,
Company XYZ, etc...

I need to create

- Forwarder zone
- Reverse Forward Zone

I can easily create a Forward Zone with domain **abc.com**
The challenge I have is that each of my customer components share the same IP address.
Hence If I create the Reverse Forward Zone I end up with something like this:

- **abc.com 1.1.1.1 host.abc.com**
- **xyz.com 1.1.1.1 host.xyz.com**

If I perform a reverse lookup on host.abc.com it works fine...but if I do a reverse lookup on 1.1.1.1 In Windows DNS I get a load balance response like this:

- 1st attempt: host.abc.com
- 2nd attempt: host.xyz.com
- 3rd attempt: host.abc.com

I want to add logic to the DNS configuration to handle DNS reverse lookup based on source machine hostname and respond with right hostname every attempt.

Workaround: Create multiple DNS but this is not scalable.

Comment: see: http://serverfault.com/questions/65781/multiple-reverse-dns-entries

Comment: @Tyson thats for serving up all the different PTRs at once. The OP wants to determine which PTR to serve based on the query source address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on the nameserver software you are using. In BIND, you would create multiple views. The view would match the source IP address of the query. In each view you would have a different configuration - all under one server instance.

Alternatively, if the source IP will always be the same, you can have the nameserver listen on multiple IP addresses, and have your views match whichever nameserver IP received the query. You can then configure each "company" to send queries to a different IP.

What you cannot do is directly match based on what the query source thinks its hostname is.

Based on the follow up comments, it appears that you were previously relying on the clients to append a specific domain to the query itself. You can do something similar in BIND as well, simply by creating zones that include that domain.

Ie, create a zone for 1.2.0.192.in-addr.arpa.foo.example.com. and another zone for 1.2.0.192.in-addr.arpa.bar.example.net. This will not work however if one of those clients does not append the domain name to its queries. Therefore you should not rely upon this method, even if it seemed to be working most of the time when you were using a Windows based nameserver.

**That said, the best approach, would simply be to use unique IP addresses!**

Comment: Thanks Joe, source request will come from same IP address but different hostname, Im planning to use BIND. Can I configure Views to match on the source hostname?

Comment: Not sure I follow.... query source has same IP, but different hostname. What do you mean by that? In what way is the hostname different?

Comment: In this multi-tenant environment each server resides in a isolated VLAN. I need to add DNS services for all VLANs and a new DNS will be located in a common accessible VLAN. Each hosts that needs DNS has the same IP (1.1.1.1) but different hostname/fqdn (computerA.companyX.com), In Windows DNS I can only create a unique ReverseLookup Zone as all share same IP Address. In this case I have a unique ReverseLookupZone 1.1.1.in-addr.CompanyX.com and I see all PTR records there. When a reverse lookup request is done from each host, Windows DNS respond with a different hostname every time.

Comment: So basically, the different hostname isnt so much the query source as it is the query itself? in other words, you're relying on the dns-suffix being different in the different queries..

Comment: I updated my answer to clarify.